# React Material UI v5 createShallow testing-util unable to be imported

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've recently upgraded from React material v4 to v5 and am having a hard time finding where to import the `createShallow` testing helper. In v4 it was imported from `import { createShallow } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';` however this doesn't seem to exist in v5. I also searched through the `@material-ui` node_module and couldn't find anything there either. The changelogs also don't mention anything about it.

Comment: They're gone. See [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/21855) pull request. Here is the relevant part from the [docs](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/testing/#userspace). They encourage you to migrate to `react-testing-library` instead.